# ResourceProvider does not send response if it's too large

Tags: movesense

I'm working with Movesense 2.0.0 on Simulator, and I'm implementing my own APIs.
This is (part of) my YAML with the API specification

```
  /hs/Log/{Log_Id}/Data:
    get:
      description: |
        Function returning Log Data
      responses:
        200:
          description: Log Data
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/LogData'
        404:
          description: Referenced log not found in LogBook.
    parameters:
       - $ref: '#/parameters/Log_Id'

parameters:
  Log_Id:
    name: Log_Id
    in: path
    required: true
    type: integer
    format: int32

definitions:
  LogData:
    required:
      - Data
    properties:
      Data:
        description: Log Data
        type: array
        items:
          type: integer
          format: int32
```

And this is the overridden method handling it:

```
void HSService::onGetRequest(const whiteboard::Request& request,
                                     const whiteboard::ParameterList& parameters)
{

    if (mModuleState != WB_RES::ModuleStateValues::STARTED)
    {
        return returnResult(request, wb::HTTP_CODE_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
    }

    switch (request.getResourceConstId())
    {
    case WB_RES::LOCAL::HS_LOG_LOG_ID_DATA::ID:
    {
            WB_RES::LogData resp;
            int32_t tmp[128] = { 0 };
            resp.data = wb::MakeArray<int32_t>(tmp, 128);
             return returnResult(request, whiteboard::HTTP_CODE_OK, ResponseOptions::Empty, resp);
        }
    }
    break;

    default:
        return returnResult(request, whiteboard::HTTP_CODE_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

When I send a request with wbcmd it hangs until it shows a 408 - Timeout, but if a make the `tmp` buffer smaller (121 or less elements) it works flawlessy.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Whiteboard has (to limit resource use on sensor) the maximum packet size which leads to maximum payload size. Currently the WB_MAX_MESSAGE_PAYLOAD_LENGTH is 466 bytes.

The Whiteboard limitations are defined in the file [WhiteboardConfig.h](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/MovesenseCoreLib/include/whiteboard/src/whiteboard/WhiteboardConfig.h)

*Full disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: Thank you. What's the suggested way to transfer larger (up to a few KB) data blocks?